# Matrix parsing in kyber

Tags: kyber, xof, shake

In the [Kyber specification](https://pq-crystals.org/kyber/data/kyber-specification-round3-20210804.pdf) the `parse` function (algorithm 1 on page 6) takes as input a non-terminating byte stream. Although unlikely, an unlimited number of bytes from this stream can be used in this function.

In `Kyber.CPAPKE.KeyGen` (algorithm 4 on page 8) the `parse` function is called on line 6 using the output of an extensible output function for the byte stream. On page 11 it is stated that `SHAKE-128` is used to instantiate this extensible output function.

The [NIST FIPS-202 specification](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) of `SHAKE-128` in section 6.2 requires that the function be given an output size *before* output is generated. How can `SHAKE-128` be used to generate the (possibly non-terminating) bytes stream of indeterminate length required by the `parse` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can $\operatorname{SHAKE-128}$ be used to generate the (possibly non-terminating) bytes stream of indeterminate length required by the parse function?

$\operatorname{SHAKE-128}$ has the property that for any message $M$ and any output lengths $d$ and $d'$ with $d<d'$, $\operatorname{SHAKE-128}(M,d)$ is the beginning of $\operatorname{SHAKE-128}(M,d')$.

The internal structure of $\operatorname{Keccak}$ and it's extension to $\operatorname{SHAKE-128}$ makes it possible to make all the computations involving $M$, then an output of length $d$, then dynamically extend the output to whatever $d'>d$ without redoing any of the previous sponge rounds already performed.

Granted, not all APIs to $\operatorname{SHAKE-128}$ allow that. E.g. I don't see how to reuse Python's [`shake_128`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#shake-variable-length-digests) to ask for more output without causing some duplicate work. We don't need to rehash $M$, but we need to recompute the whole output.